# Ajax POST request not being sent?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am simply grabbing a value froma  input field and displaying it with php after the button is pressed.

It does display but it doesnt give the value of the post variable, This is the html and script i am trying to use:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function chk()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var dataString='name'+ name;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'hi.php',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }


            })
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return chk()">
        <p id="msg"></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

the page that it is being sent to for php processing is  this:

```
 <?php 
     session_start();
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     echo "Response:".$name;
  ?>
```

Am I not sending the POST corectly with the `Ajax`?

Comment: You're missing the `=` in the `dataString`: `var dataString = 'name=' + name;`

Comment: Getting any value at console ?Open console and see ajax page is actually called or not .

Comment: @Rory there is a `=` there...? and @Bikash the console doesnt throw any errors it is just blank, the page i have it hosted on is [link](http://hgsystems.us/users/tmcc/testing/ajax/hey.php)

Comment: @Apparatus17 you need to add an `=` in the string itself, after 'name'

Comment: @rory ah ok i see could i just use var dataString = { 'name': name }; as the answer down below suggest?

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way so that you don't have to also deal with encoding it.

Comment: ok thank you i understand now, whats with the down vote of my question?

Comment: it's a typo, and typo questions are only useful to one person. not useful questions get downvotes

Comment: @Kevin B fair enough thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 3):

first thing I would do is change your datastring:

```
var dataString = 'name' + name;
```

to

```
var dataString = { 'name': name };
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the curly brackets in the variable?

Comment: @Apparatus17 That's an object notation.

Comment: I deleted my comment, I realized I mistyped. passing an object will fix encoding problems and still post each as separate POST fields.

Answer (score 0):

it should be a key value pair i.e. you are sending the post variable correctly
your should write/send like dataString = {'name': your_value, 'otherName': 'someting'};